# Integrate with facebook in android

Tags: android, facebook

I have to integrate with facebook in android application.

Here i have to click the button means the fb login page is opened.if i have to entered the correct login page means the post to wall is opened.

Here i have to write the some text means it is post to fb wall successfully.But i wish to pass the string value here.that string value is display on that edittext box also post on wall.how can i do ???

I have using below code:

```
public class AndroidFacebookConnectActivity extends Activity {

// Your Facebook APP ID
private static String APP_ID = "xxxxx"; // Replace with your App ID

// Instance of Facebook Class
private Facebook facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
private AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner;
String FILENAME = "AndroidSSO_data";
private SharedPreferences mPrefs;


Button btnFbLogin;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    btnFbLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_fblogin);
    mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
    btnFbLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("Image Button", "button Clicked");
            loginToFacebook();
        }
    });
  }


public void loginToFacebook() {

    mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
    long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);

    if (access_token != null) {
        facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);

        btnFbLogin.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        postToWall();
    Log.d("FB Sessions", "" + facebook.isSessionValid());
    }

    if (expires != 0) {
        facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
    }

    if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) {
        facebook.authorize(this,
                new String[] { "email", "publish_stream" },
                new DialogListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        // Function to handle cancel event
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {

                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                        editor.putString("access_token",
                                facebook.getAccessToken());
                        editor.putLong("access_expires",
                                facebook.getAccessExpires());
                        editor.commit();
                      btnFbLogin.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                   postToWall();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(DialogError error) {
                        // Function to handle error

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError fberror) {
                        // Function to handle Facebook errors

                    }

                });
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
public void postToWall() {
    // post on user's wall.
    facebook.dialog(this, "feed", new DialogListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(DialogError e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            String sh="Krish";
            Bundle params = new Bundle();

            params.putString("message", sh);
            params.putString("name", sh);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
        }
    });

}}
```

Here how can i post the **String sh="Krish";** value on FB wall.how can i display these Krish value on fb text.please give me some suggestions...

**EDIT:**

This is my updated onComplete code:

```
@Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            String sh="Krish";
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("caption",sh);
            }
```

But now also am getting same error ly.how can i resolve these .please help me.

[image: visit these]

Here i have to wrote the text **Hi**.These Hi is posted successfully.But i wish to display the **Krish** on that edittext box dynamically.How can i do ????

Comment: @Nezam i have tried.but i didn't get it.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your `OnComplete`

```
params.putString("caption",sh);
```

Comment: Hi that ly me also already wrote :params.putString("message", sh); but it is not displayed.

Comment: Please look into the answer properly i am saying to change "message" to "caption".. did you try that?

Comment: This is my OnComplete code yar:@Override
   public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
    String sh="Krish";
    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("caption",sh);
    }
didn't get these text on wall.

Comment: i have to wrote something on that edittext means that text is posted well.but i wish to display the Krish on that edittext box dynamically.now nothing is display on that edittext box.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are using Facebook SDK 3?

According to these lines:

```
private Facebook facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
private AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner;
```

I think you are using old SDK which so many of methods are deprecated.

Comment: yes...now i have added facebook sdk 3 ly.am getting from https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk...now also am getting same ly. have to wrote the text Hi.These Hi is posted successfully.But i wish to display the Krish on that edittext box dynamically.How can i do ???